# COM Error in ADODB connection

Tags: vb.net, com, oledb

In my console application i have this simple database connectivity code. But it shows COM exception error in ADODB.Connection line.

```
  Module Module1    
        Sub Main()
            Dim cn As New ADODB.Connection() //error 
            cn.ConnectionString = "provider=sqloledb;server=localhost;database=northwind;uid=<username>"
            cn.Open()
        End Sub    
    End Module
```

I added `Microsoft Activex Data objects 2.8` library in reference,but error appeared.
I changes the library to Microsoft Activex Data objects 6.0 library, but still it shows the error.
When i run the applicaiton first it shows one error-

*`The procedure entry point _LoadVersionedResourceEx@16 could not be located in MSDART.dll.`*

and then

```
COM Exception unhandled:
Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {00000514-0000-0010-8000-00AA006D2EA4} failed due to the following error: 8007007f The specified procedure could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007F).
```

Im using windows 7, Visual studio 2010, vb.net

Comment: It is not supposed to have that entrypoint.  This is an ugly DLL Hell problem, some installer probably copied an old version of ADO onto your machine.  You'll need to get your machine fixed, probably by running the MDAC installer.  Best place to ask is superuser.com

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have an obsolete `Msdart.dll` file in your `%windir%\System32`

Replace it with the correct `Msdart.dll (v2.71.9031.4)` file that is located in your `%windir%\System32\Dllcache` folder.

Another work around is to include `Microsoft Data Access Components` library in `Project > Add reference > COM tab`

Comment: in windows directory i could not find dllcache folder. In my system32 i have msdart.dll with version 6.1.7600.16385

Comment: Did you tried to include `Microsoft Data Access Components` reference to your project?